# Django get Data from API

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i'm using Django Rest Framework (DRF) to build API in my project. And i want to get the data from API URL in my views.py.

This is my services.py

```
import requests
import json

def get_user(username, first_name):
    url = 'http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users/'
    # headers = {'Accept':'application/json', 'Content-Type':'application/json'}
    params = {'username': username, 'first_name': first_name}
    r = requests.get(url, params=params)
    data=str(r)
    user_list = json.dumps(data)
    return user_list
```

and this is my views.py

```
class test(APIView):
    permission_classes = [permissions.IsAuthenticated, TokenHasReadWriteScope]
    def get(self,request):
        lists = services.get_user('Fahmi', 'Fahmi')
        return Response({"success": True, "content": lists})
```

And i got an error below

From postman :

```
{
    "content": "\"<Response [401]>\"",
    "success": true
}
```

From terminal :

```
"GET /api/v1/users/?username=Fahmi&first_name=Fahmi HTTP/1.1" 401 58
```

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: [401 Unauthorized](https://httpstatuses.com/401), you should add Auth header, read the [way-to-test-token-based-auth](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25534337/whats-the-proper-way-to-test-token-based-auth-using-apirequestfactory)

Comment: @BearBrown thak you.. i didn't think of that. I will try

Answer (score 1):

So in `services.py` you do a request to another server in `http://localhost:8000/api/v1/users/`. You are not authorized to access that, hence the [401 error](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/401).